# Entity Framework: Saving an edited entity works twice but gives errors after that

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to update an entry in my database through a put request in a C# API.

This is the code to edit the entity:

```
[HttpPut("user")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser([FromForm]int id, [FromForm]string name)
{
    Users user = _context.Users.Find(id);
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.Name = name;
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return NoContent();
    }
    return NotFound();
}
```

The database model:

```
public class Users
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

On the first time calling the API it works just fine. No errors:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (30ms) [Parameters=[@p1='?' (DbType = Int32), @p0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      UPDATE [Users] SET [Name] = @p0
      OUTPUT 1
      WHERE [Id] = @p1;
```

On the second time calling the API it says that it failed but the entity gets edited:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (107ms) [Parameters=[@p1='?' (DbType = Int32), @p0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      UPDATE [Users] SET [Name] = @p0
      OUTPUT 1
      WHERE [Id] = @p1;
```

After that it gives the same error but doesn't work anymore:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[@p1='?' (DbType = Int32), @p0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      UPDATE [Users] SET [Name] = @p0
      OUTPUT 1
      WHERE [Id] = @p1;
```

I looked at the variables with breakpoints and it looks like the issue is part of the SaveChanges. The user.Name gets changed without problems but when it should be saved the database gives an error.

What I noticed is that the error doesn't happen when you submit the exactly same string. If there is only a slight change in the string the issue happens.

Comment: Which lifetime has your DbContext? I assume Scoped?

Comment: Always await async calls, e.g. `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`. Also, not strongly necessary, but use (and await) async method versions if exist, e.g. `user = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);`